# PHP Array file_get_contents for each query

Tags: php, arrays, file-get-contents

Using the following code:

```
<?php
$url = $_GET['name'];
$nurl = str_replace('%3B', ';', $url);
$arr = explode("=", $nurl);
$rValue = parse_url($nurl, PHP_URL_QUERY);
preg_match_all('/\w+=.*/',$rValue,$matches);
parse_str($matches[0][0], $output);
parse_str($rValue);
echo $rValue;
?>
```

I get the following output:

```
field1=6918795;6990788;21434586&person144453469&number1=7412127;11425470;31104141&person86762935&number2=9152334;26300968;26441141&person38579423&number3=7897334;9114514;11656368;13683203
```

The question:

How to get file get contents from an URL for each query?

Example:

File get contents for field1 (of which the number 1 is a variable)

File get contents for 6918795

File get contents for 6990788

File get contents for 21434586

File get contents for person144453469 (the number 144453469 is a variable)
etc.

Comment: Question not clear. What exactly you trying to do? Why you are creating this output from the script you mentioned?

Comment: Is your script fetching data from other sites or are you simply trying to pass the request parameters sent by your clients' browser?

Comment: @Abhishek the user is inserting a link (from a website) via submit form and I simply slice it to get only the part I'm interested in and get the infos I need via API.

Comment: @JuliePelletier data from other sites, that's why I want to use file_get_contents.

Comment: Ok that makes sense but I really don't get your logic of doing file_get_contents on parameter values.

Comment: @JuliePelletier each parameter represents an "item" that I want to display info about.

Answer (score 0):

```
$var = field1=6918795;6990788;21434586&person144453469&number1=7412127;11425470;31104141&person86762935&number2=9152334;26300968;26441141&person38579423&number3=7897334;9114514;11656368;13683203
```

First separate by &

```
$separated_by_ands = explode('&', $var) ;

foreach($separated_by_ands as $separated_by_and) {
  $separated_by_equals = explode('=', $separated_by_and);
  $separated_by_equals = $separated_by_equals[1];
  $separated_by_semicolons = explode(';', $separated_by_equals);
  foreach($separated_by_semicolons as $number) {
    //do file get contents for $number
   } 
 }
```

*yes I know bad choice of variable names :P*